# Bluemix BXNUI2081E error when uploading an SSL certificate for a custom domain

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to upload an SSL certificate for a custom domain in Bluemix, but I'm getting a generic error:

> BXNUI2081E: An unknown error occurred when modifying certificates and keys: local:///deploySNIArtifacts/mbaasUtilities.xsl:793: Type of the left-hand side of / operator must be a nodeset..

I've followed the documentation, using openssl to generate a self-signed certificate, using the wildcard form of my domain.   Any ideas on what I might have missed?

Here's a slightly redacted version of the output from the certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 17167458275182091963 (0xee3f10581c919ebb)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=Massachusetts, L=Littleton, O=IBM, OU=CLMServices, CN=*.clmsvcs.ibmcloud.com/emailAddress=<email removed>
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr 19 13:36:39 2016 GMT
            Not After : May 19 13:36:39 2016 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=Massachusetts, L=Littleton, O=IBM, OU=CLMServices, CN=*.clmsvcs.ibmcloud.com/emailAddress=<email removed>
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
<<data removed>>
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
<<data removed>>
```

Comment: show what's on line 793 of that file...

Comment: mbaasUtilities.xsl is Bluemix source code that I don't have.    It would be interesting to know what it is trying to parse, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

The only case I've seen this error was when the private key you are using does not match the certificate.

You can run the following 2 commands to check if the private key and certificate you are trying to upload match:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key | openssl md5
```

Output from both commands needs to be the same.

Comment: The output is the same for my certificate and my key.

Comment: OK, thanks for checking. Is it possible to print the certificate text and add it to your question? Here is the command I'd like to see the output: `openssl x509 -in certificate.cer -text -noout`

Comment: Added the output to the question text.

Comment: ok thanks. I will try to recreate your problem later today and update the answer with my findings

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away after a few days.   I was able to upload the keys successfully.